# The code works incorrectly and displays incomprehensible numbers:

Tags: python-3.x, hex, decimal

The code works incorrectly and displays incomprehensible numbers:
**3.612432554629948e + 76**
Displays incomprehensible values,it should be like this:
And should output:
A large number for example:
HEX: 8459f630cd86ddfa329b3d13d5217d45df1d5e9a56a63f6a3d7ab8b794c35c12
DEC: 59864244547079690871082685810675850360550404961977540588162601013229404773394

```
# Covert a file with lines of hex values in "hex.txt" to decimal
# values and write to "dec.txt"

# NOTE: This program only handles Value errors and replaces them
# with the string XXXXX, no other error handling is performed  

HEXLIST_FILENAME = "hex.txt"
DECLIST_FILENAME = "dec.txt"

def loadHex():
    """
    Returns a list of Hex strings from a file
    
    """
    hexList = []
    print ("Loading hex list from file...")
    try:
        inFile = open(HEXLIST_FILENAME, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print('No such file "hex.txt"')
        #more error handeling here
    for line in inFile:
        hexList.append(line.strip().upper())
    print (len(hexList)), "Numbers loaded."
    return hexList

def hexToDec(hexString):
    """
    Takes in a string representing a hex value
    
    Returns a decimal number string
    """
    try:
        i=int(hexString,16)
    except ValueError:
        print('Oops! There was an invalid number in hex.txt...')
        print('Invalid number replaced with XXXXX')
        i='XXXXX'
    return str(i/float(2**21))

def exportDec(decList):
    """


    """
    outFile=open(DECLIST_FILENAME,'w')
    for num in decList:
        outFile.write(num+"\n")

    outFile.close()
    print ("Success! Decimal numbers written to dec.txt")


decList = []
hexVals=loadHex()
for hexnum in hexVals:
    decList.append(hexToDec(hexnum))

exportDec(decList)

s=input()('Press Enter to exit...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are dividing the converted value by 2**21 in your hexToDec method:

```
return str(i/float(2**21))
```

The division is unnecessary and you would get the correct output if you just

```
return str(i)
```

directly from your hexToDec method.

Comment: I checked now it gives 1.0
1.0
1.0

Comment: Thank you Niraj Gupta everything worked out